# adding android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen" while still supporting older sdk

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to modify my widget so that it supports being placed on 4.2 lockscreens.  However I still want to support older SDK's.

I added

```
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
```

to my appwidget-provider in res/xml, but eclipse complains that there is "no resource identifier found for attribute widetCategory in package android'

If I raise the minSdkVerion to 17 everything works fine, but I want to still support older SDKs.

I have tried using resource qualifiers creating a separte res/xml-v17/mywidget.xml and only adding the tag there, but the error still appears.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
I figured it out.  using a res/xml-v17/ folder is the answer.  I just had to change the build target for my project to 17 / 4.2.

Answer (score 9):

I think that setting `targetSdk` to `17` is enough. XML elements that do not make sense on older SDKs are simply ignored.

No need to put mywidget.xml into `res/xml-v17` folder

Answer (score 6):

*Put a copy of your mywidget.xml in res/xml-v17/ folder.
This targets Android 4.2 and all new "properties on the appwidget-provider element will be avaible. Also right click your project in eclipse and change build target to: API level 17/ Android 4.2*

I saw your Edit. But i think this makes it more clear that this question have an answer.

**UPDATE:** I can confirm Tomáš Hubálek answer. the xml-v17 is not needed. Changing Build target is enough. Right click your project in eclipse and change **build target** to: API level 17/ Android 4.2